# PHP dynamic include and javascript fade - Images not working

Tags: php, ajax, image, include

My site has dynamically included content through PHP and jQuery fading in/out the content of the site, in order for the page not to refresh.

The only problem is, since i added the the java fade in/out my images on the loaded content is not shown. The box for the image is shown, but it acts like there is image in the directory.

my html and php include from my index.php:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <?php include('header.php') ?>

            <div id="menu">
                <?php include('menu.php') ?>
            </div>

            <hr class="topline" />
            <hr class="bottom-line" />
        </div>
    <div id="content">
        <?php
            $content = $_GET['content'];
            $pages = array('forside', 'menukort', 'hvemervi', 'Kontakt', 'catering');
            if (!empty($content)) {
                if(in_array($content, $pages)) {
                    $content .= '.php';
                    include($content);
                } else {
                    echo 'Siden kunne ikke findes. Der må være sket en fejl! Gå tlbage til <a href="index.php">forsiden</a>';
                }
            } else {
                include('pages/forside.php');
            }   
        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <?php include('footer.php') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a pastebin of my javascript fade in/out: http://pastebin.com/YN3pUvnq

Here's a live version of the site: http://wonzentest.wonzen.dk

Frontpage should contain a javascript gallery/slideshow coded like this:

```
<script class="secret-source">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
        animtype      : 'slide',
        height        : 480,
        width         : 960,
        responsive    : true,
        randomstart   : true,
        nexttext : '<div class="hovernavright"><img src="../Images/leftarrow.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" /></div>',
        prevtext : '<div class="hovernavleft"><img src="../Images/rightarrow.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" /></div>',
        usecaptions : true,
        automatic : true
      });

    });
</script>
```

```
<div id="banner-slide">
    <ul class="bjqs">
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/Wonzenmad.jpg" title="WONZEN ER THAT BOOMB" /></li>
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/Wonzenmad.jpg" title="Velkommen til Wonzen!" /></li>
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/Wonzenmad1.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad3.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/Wonzenmad2.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad4.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad5.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad6.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad7.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad8.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad9.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
        <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad10.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Everything worked fine until i started using the fade. 
All other images that bother me are done with

```
<img src="../Images/HQ/imagename.jpg" />
```

**EDIT:**

For no apparent reason the images decided to work when uploaded to the remote server.. hmm.. 
Allthough when I press the frontpage menu button and see the frontpage the java slideshow is not displayed, or it is displayed but to only some of it(it's misplaced).

When you firdt load the page, the script works fine.. 
I'm so lost here.

Comment: `Java` and is not the same as `JavaScript`. It is like `Car` and `Carpet`, `Ham` and `Hamster`.

Comment: I know :S. My bad. I was just shortining it down. Since i wrote javascript in title @Pshemo.
Do you know why it's causing me trouble though?

Comment: It appears to be working on the live site? I don't understand the problem, then.

Comment: @SetSailMedia Yes it does. But when you press the menu button for the frontpage the slideshow dont show correctly for some reason.